# My question is for a form field that client required convert if typed numbers to proper date format in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript

My client is required date format in `mm/dd/yyyy` format that they type numbers or date format if format is not match with above format it show error message. Can anyone help me?

I use this Javascript in custom validation script section.

```
var v = event.value;
var d = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", v);

if (d == null) {
    event.value = "";
    app.alert("Invalid date. Please check and re-enter (mm/dd/yyyy).");
}
```

And I also insert Arbitrary Mask in Format section 99/99/9999

But problem is when I insert date like 12/12/201 it shows error message that wrong format and text cursor is return to field but when I insert 13/12/2019 it shows also error message but text cursor jump to next field. My client want this to not happen if format is wrong not jump to next field.

Is this possible? Any help is respectful Appreciation. Thank in Advance if any solution.

first error message :
[image: first error message]

problem with first error message :
[image: problem with first error message]

second error message :
[image: second error message]

but this is OK in second error message :
[image: but this is OK in second error message]

Comment: Your date `12/12/201` is not in proper format i.e `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: What is  the value of `v` ?

Comment: Prasad Telkikar... this is a Ok that I've not type proper format the error message show and text cursor come in same filed but when I use 13/12/2019 the error message show but text cursor jump to next field.

Comment: I just copy and paste a script b'coz I'm not professional developer so I dont have knowledge that what is the value of v